# awk code to read two arrays

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two arrays. I need to loop through array 1 a row at a time. For each row in array 1 there are transactional records in array 2. I need to print the transactional record for each row in array 1 that matches on a primary key shared between the two array. So think of it like a bank account. Array 1 have 6 account and array 2 has all the transaction for each account. How do I print to a file the account information in array 1 on the first follow by a line break then all the transaction for that account. Both file are using the account number to match records. I need to use "awk" in bash scripting.

Comment: Welcome to U&L.  I probably won't be the only one to ask that you supply some example input and together with desired output.

Comment: Array 1
content1, content2, primaryKey1, content1, content1
content2, content2, primaryKey2, content2, content2
content3, content3, primaryKey3, content3, content3

Array 2
data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1
data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3
datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2

Output
content1, content2, primaryKey1, content1, content1
data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1
content2, content2, primaryKey2, content2, content2
datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2
content3, content3, primaryKey3, content3, content3
data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3

Comment: Not sure if my reply was format correctly. I am not familiar on how to use this tool so my apologies.

Comment: @Kwesi, edit your original question, and ass the example there (as then the formatting will be retained).

Comment: @Kwesi, are you sure that AWK is the right tool for the job?
A `bash` script (which may use AWK), or a `python` script, seem like more suitable tools for this problem.

Comment: Perhaps the homework assignment insists that `awk` be used here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if awk or bash will accomplish my task. I am still trying to learn both. I appreciate any direction. I do have to use a Shell script so either bash or awk. I thought a nested for loop with a condition check on the main loop key will determine if the second loop will print transaction records.

```
for (key in Authorization_Arr)
            {   
                print "SASH1" Authorization_Arr[key] > "output.csv"

                for (i in LineItem_Arr)
                {
                    split(LineItem_Arr[i], a, ", ")
                    if (a[2] == key) 
                    {
                        print LineItem_Arr[i] > "output.csv";
                    }

                }
            }
```